# is there any bs4 function to print the structure shown below?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

Actually I am developing a program that shows state vise details in india about Corona pandemic.. I done everything but stucked at printing the tags. I mean I want show the details like this
**Edit :** when user input the state name I want to show the only details of that state...

*output should be like this*

**Name of state :  xxxxx**

**Active cases :xxxx**

**cured/discharged : xxxx**

**Deaths : xxxx**

**Total cases : xxxx**

Here is my python code

````
import requests

#this url site provides latest info about Corona cases in table format 
url="https://www.mohfw.gov.in/"

data=requests.get(url)

soup=BeautifulSoup(data.text,"html.parser")

for _1st_cell in soup.find_all('tr')[1:] :
    if _1st_cell!=None:
        _1st_cell.td.decompose()
        
for _1st_heading in soup.find_all('th')[0]:
    if _1st_heading!=None:
        _1st_heading.decompose()

for row in soup.findAll('tr'):
    garbage=row.find('td',colspan='6')
    garbage2=row.find('td',colspan='1')
    
    if garbage!=None:
        row.decompose()
    elif garbage2!=None:
        row.decompose()
    elif row!=None:
        print(row.text)
        
for heading in soup.find_all('th'):
    print(heading.text+": ")```
````

Comment: What's wrong with your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.mohfw.gov.in/'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

for tr in soup.table.select('tr:has(td)'):
    tds = [td.get_text(strip=True) for td in tr.select('td')]
    if len(tds) == 6 and tds[0].isnumeric():
        print('Name of state    :', tds[1])
        print('Active cases     :', tds[2])
        print('Cured/discharged :', tds[3])
        print('Deaths           :', tds[4])
        print('Total cases      :', tds[5])
        print('-' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
Name of state    : Andaman and Nicobar Islands
Active cases     : 52
Cured/discharged : 142
Deaths           : 0
Total cases      : 194
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Name of state    : Andhra Pradesh
Active cases     : 19814
Cured/discharged : 20298
Deaths           : 534
Total cases      : 40646
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

... and so on.
```

Comment: Thank you so much bro! I was finding this output from 2 days finally got it I am very grateful of you...!          bro can help me a little bit how to print only one state details that what user input if user input Maharashtra then I only want to show he details of maharashtra state